# How to get top n lines from the cell of table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which i have one row and three columns. In column C, We have multiple lines in the cell. How can i search 'hi' in top 3 lines of column C.  i am interested to search a pattern in top n lines  of Column C.

Suppose below is the table:

**----A  -----B ------C**

----as-----de -----ef

-------------------jk

-------------------lm

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What RDBMS? Some of them support regular expressions, which _may_ be able to get you what you want.

Comment: Do you have multiple lines in the same row or do you talk about multiple rows in the same table?

Comment: *top n lines of column C* following what order?, there is not an implicit or natural order for a table

Comment: I am using SQL. Suppose we have 1 row and 3 columns. In the third column, we have text of multiple lines. i am just interested to search a pattern in top n lines of third column.

Comment: Michael,   could u please provide me a link in which we use regular expression ?

Comment: What RDBMS? What order determines top?

Comment: MySQL. I am unable to create table correctly.

Comment: Can you normalize your table such that instead of having multiple lines of text in one column, you have another table that links to the primary key of `TableA` and contains each row of text on a separate line? Working with multiple rows combined in a single row can be nightmarish to deal with.

Comment: I have only 1 row and 3 columns. limit size word is in 1 and 2nd columns but text of multiple lines in column 3. I want to search a pattern in top n lines of third column .

Comment: must it search only the single row's cell C, or in all rows cell C's?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a single row you need to search, you can do something like this (you'll need to get your text into @cellText, and set @n with the number of lines, and adjust the line-break characters, and rewrite for mySQL):

```
declare @n int
set @n = 2

declare @cellText varchar(100)
select @cellText = '1xxx
2xxx
3xxx
4xxx'
---------------------------

declare @textToSearch varchar(100)
set @textToSearch = ''

declare @counter int
set @counter = 0
while charindex( CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), @cellText) > 0 
begin
   set @counter = @counter + 1
   set @textToSearch = @textToSearch + LEFT(@cellText, charindex( CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), @cellText)+1)
   set @cellText = SUBSTRING(@cellText, charindex( CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@cellText)+2, LEN(@cellText))
   if @counter = @n break
end
if @n > @counter and LEN(@cellText) > 0 set @textToSearch = @textToSearch + @cellText

-- search your text here
select @textToSearch
```